# FactoryGirl: create factories for model with private class method new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I use non-AR model with a factory method on it.

```
class MyModel
  include ActiveAttr::Model

  attribute :data
  attribute :frequency

  def self.process_data
    # ...
    new(data: 'foo', frequency: 1) # e. g.
  end
  private_class_method :new
end
```

The default factory invokation of cource would throw an error: **private method `new' called for MyModel** Are there any special options for the factory to be set in order to omit this error?

Comment: why do you want your `:new` method to be private?

Comment: @TheCha͢mp in such a way factory method is implemented - when you want instantiate an object with different options for different cases. Rather than invoking with new, one could invoke it with `MyModel.process_data`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into [`initialize_with`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#custom-construction).

```
class A
  class << self
    private :new
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :a do
    initialize_with { A.send :new }
  end
end

FactoryGirl.build :a
#<C:0x007ff1219f0190>
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you.